# How to get mesos log dir

Tags: mesos

I want to get mesos log dir like this

```
mesos-master --zk=zk://localhost:2181/mesos --log_dir=/Users/wangyao/WorkAndLog/mesos/log
```

/Users/wangyao/WorkAndLog/meoso/log

How could i get this in my code?

I try it with do GetRequest in my code like this

```
GetRequestHandler requestHandler = new GetRequestHandler() {
      @Override
      public String doGetRequestCallBack(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
      }
    };
    Map<String, String> httpParams     = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String obj = HttpClientUtils.doGetRequest("http", "localhost", 5050, "/master/state.json", httpParams,
         requestHandler);
```

in this way I can get the log_dir in the obj.

but I knew that the application server and mesos server is not using the same machine ,so  I can't do the request with 'localhost',  Generally it's not a viable way.
is there any way to get the log_dir?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: what problem are you trying to solve? You speak about log_dir, but try to get state.json from the master in your code snippet.

Comment: i am developing a web app likes apache marathon,  and i want to run a deamon job on my app,    this deamon job need  to download some files like tomcat.zip from other website,   and i want to download these files to the mesos log dir,  i don't know the way that marathon do it ;

Comment: have you ever used  marathon ?,   it download these files to mesos log dir,,,and the command they do is not include '$ cd /Users/xxx/mesos/xx/log' ,  but finally , these files are in this log dir.

Comment: My Englishi is not very well,  could you understand me ?..   - -||

Comment: Marathon does not download anything to the Mesos log dir. Maybe if you could explain in a bit more detail what exactly you are trying to do, someone could help you.

Comment: Your English is quite fine, no worries! First off, Marathon is not Apache Marathon : ), though it is open source, it is mainly supported and developed by a commercial company (Mesosphere). Second, why do you want to download files to the log dir? You should either use your task's sandbox for that (make sure to request enough disk resources!) or let Mesos to fetch them for you.

Comment: `{
  "id": "tomcat",
  "cmd": "mv *.war apache-tomcat-*/webapps && cd apache-tomcat-* && sed \"s/8002/$PORT/g\" < ./conf/server.xml > ./conf/server-mesos.xml && ./bin/catalina.sh run -config ./conf/server-mesos.xml",
  "mem": 512,
  "cpus": 1.0,
  "instances": 1,
  "uris": [
    "http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.62/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.62.tar.gz",
    "https://gwt-examples.googlecode.com/files/Calendar.war"
  ]
}`    this is the marathon example ,  what they do is that download tomcat.zip,Calendar.war, then unzip tomcat.zip,then move the .war to tomcat/webapps

Comment: last start the tomcat,     and where these files download  to ?   in mesos's localhost:5050 ,i can see it from the sandbox, they download it  to the log_dir , the route is  `Users/wangyao /WorkAndLog/mesos/work/slaves  20150703-100047-3047729344-5050-1590-S0/frameworks /20150703-095320-3047729344-5050-502-0000/executors/61/runs/27113b00-68db-4ad4-8c85-480a0b939bd3`

Comment: but i browse the sandbox's `stdout` ,   i found the shell command which marathon do is just `mv *.war apache-tomcat-*/webapps && cd apache-tomcat-* && sed \"s/8002/$PORT/g\" < ./conf/server.xml > ./conf/server-mesos.xml && ./bin/catalina.sh run -config ./conf/server-mesos.xml`

Comment: i am confused that when marathon download these files ?   and How do they konw my machines log_dir is `Users/wangyao /WorkAndLog/mesos/work/slaves ` ?   please help me .~~Thanks